# Cplex 12.10 and python

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

Does cplex 12.10 support python 3.8? I cannot install setup.py file. I think only 3.7 and 3.6 are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Googling turned up an answer immediately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377839/i-have-a-error-on-installing-cplex-12-10-to-python-3-8. Apparently you just have to rename a folder.